# Convert date (year, month, day) to Julian Day Number and back to date

Tags: c#, calendar, julian-date

I am trying to implement two functions, 1) converting a date to Julian Day Number and 2) Converting Julian Day Number back to Date (year, month and day). The result that my code returns is off by one day. I am not familiar with how the algorithm works but I can see that if I take the `Math.Ceiling` of Julian number it works but I am not sure it is the best way to fix the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
public class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts year, month and day to a Julian number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="year"></param>
    /// <param name="month"></param>
    /// <param name="day"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static decimal JulianNumber(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        decimal a, b, c, e, f;

        if (month == 1 || month == 2)
        {
            year -= 1;
            month += 12;
        }
        a = Math.Truncate((decimal) year / 100);
        b = Math.Truncate(a / 4);
        c = 2 - a + b;
        e = Math.Truncate((365.25m * (year + 4716)));
        f = Math.Truncate((30.6001m * (month + 1)));

        return (c + day + e + f - 1524.5m);
        // return Math.Ceiling(c + day + e + f - 1524.5m);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts Julian number to year, month and day
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="julianNumber"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static (int year, int month, int day) GregorianDate(decimal julianNumber)
    {
        int l, n, i, j, k;

        l = (int)julianNumber + 68569;
        n = 4 * l / 146097;
        l = l - (146097 * n + 3) / 4;
        i = 4000 * (l + 1) / 1461001;
        l = l - 1461 * i / 4 + 31;
        j = 80 * l / 2447;
        k = l - 2447 * j / 80;
        l = j / 11;
        j = j + 2 - 12 * l;
        i = 100 * (n - 49) + i + l;

        return (i, j, k);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var (year1, month1, day1) = (2010, 1, 2);

        var (year2, month2, day2) = GregorianDate(JulianNumber(year1, month1, day1));

        Console.WriteLine(year1 == year2);     // True
        Console.WriteLine(month1 == month2);   // True
        Console.WriteLine(day1 == day2);       // False!
    }
}
```

Comment: Being this one of the possible implementations of one of the possible algorithms, you should show us where you took the algorithm from...

Comment: As a curiosity: http://apps.burlock.org/julian-date-in-c/

Comment: @xanatos I got it from here: https://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm

Comment: @nodejs Your JulianNumber is totally different from the one in the linked url. That is `jd = ( 1461 * ( y + 4800 + ( m - 14 ) / 12 ) ) / 4 +
          ( 367 * ( m - 2 - 12 * ( ( m - 14 ) / 12 ) ) ) / 12 -
          ( 3 * ( ( y + 4900 + ( m - 14 ) / 12 ) / 100 ) ) / 4 +
          d - 32075` with only integer divisions (*Division is to be understood as in integer arithmetic, with remainders discarded, and (m-14)/12 is -1 for m <= 2 and is 0 otherwise.*)

Comment: And note that your rounding problem could be caused by the fact that a julian day begins at noo... So 28 may 2018 00.00 is 2458266.5 . Try for example http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of Julian Day. Taken from the page you linked:

> Following Herschel's lead astronomers adopted this system and took noon GMT -4712-01-01 JC (January 1st, 4713 B.C.) as their zero point

So 2018-05-28 at 00.00 is 2458266.5, while 2018-05-28 at 12.00 is 2458267. If you watch your `JulianNumber` withut the `Math.Ceiling` in fact returns 2458266.5. Now, [the page you linked](https://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm) (from which you took the *second* method, `GregorianDate`, uses only integers, so it works for dates that are at noon (12.00). So by rounding up (ceiling) the result of `JulianNumber` you are moving the date to the 12.00 hour, and making it "compatible" with the `GregorianDate`.

Possible solutions: use for `JulianNumber` the algorithm that is present in the [same page](https://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm) and use only `int` everywhere (to show the fact that you are ignoring hours, minutes, seconds), or search for another algorithm for `GregorianDate`.